# Mysql Query Issue Date minus 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

This keeps coming up with an error and I cant figure out why...

```
SELECT
  i.user_id
FROM (SELECT
    SUM(us.score) AS score_sum,
    us.user_id
      FROM user_scores us
      WHERE us.created >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      GROUP BY us.user_id) AS i
ORDER BY i.score_sum
LIMIT 1
```

exception 'CDbException' with message

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "7": syntax error.

The SQL statement executed was:

```
SELECT
  i.user_id
FROM (SELECT
    SUM(us.score) AS score_sum,
    us.user_id
      FROM user_scores us
      WHERE us.created >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      GROUP BY us.user_id) AS i
ORDER BY i.score_sum
LIMIT 1



<?php

class WinnerCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function actionSelect()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT i.user_id FROM
            (SELECT SUM(us.score) AS score_sum, us.user_id FROM user_scores us
            WHERE us.created >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
            GROUP BY us.user_id) AS i
            ORDER BY i.score_sum
            LIMIT 1";
        $user_id = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();
        echo $user_id;
        return $user_id;
    }
```

}

?>

Comment: What data type is `created` in your table?

Comment: What API are you calling this through? Are you using a prepared statement placeholder anywhere?

Comment: If you execute the query directly as you have it above in a client, does it run (looks like it should)? What MySQL version?

Comment: Created is a timestamp.

Comment: I am using this inside of the Yii framework.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes Michael, it runs directly on MySQL with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot explain the problem, but you can eliminate the subquery in the expression.  Perhaps that will help:

```
        SELECT us.user_id
        FROM user_scores us
        WHERE us.created >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
        GROUP BY us.user_id)
        ORDER BY SUM(us.score)
        LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I don't think we can use an aggregate (`SUM`) inside the ORDER BY close.

Comment: @artragis . . . That is allowed, in MySQL and in every other database that I know of that supports SQL.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that, happy to have opened this topic.